# How to animate particular image on click in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, animation

**This is my code I am using angular animation, I want to animate particular image using this code. Any help is much appreciated.**

```
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let image of images">
    <td>{{image.id}}</td>
    <td><p [@myAwesomeAnimations]='state' (click)="animateMe()"> <img style="width:250px" src="http://localhost:8000{{image.image}}"/></p></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="delete(image)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>           
    </table>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    animations: [
        trigger('myAwesomeAnimations',[
        state('small',style({
            transform: 'scale(1)',
        })),
        state('large',style({
          transform: 'scale(1.2)',
        })),
        transition('small<=>large', animate('300ms ease-in',keyframes([
          style({opacity: 0,transform: 'translateY(-75%)',offset:0}),
          style({opacity: 1,transform: 'translateY(35px)',offset: .5}),
          style({opacity: 1,transform: 'translateY(0)',offset:1}),
        ]))),
        ]),
    ]

    })
```

when i am click  an image then its animate all images

Comment: can you show us full code in stackblitz (set code fork and post link):https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6

Comment: can you show us your `animateMe()/delete(image)` functions

Comment: when you use a "variable" in animation [@myAwesomeAnimations]='state', the only thing is change the value of the variable: animateMe(){this.state='small'}.

Comment: animateMe(){
    this.state = (this.state ==='small' ? 'large' :'small');
  }

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfxfx3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why all the images animates because, it is bounded to a single property which is 
`state`, so to fix it, each items on your `images` should have its own state animation property

Try to re-model your `images` and add a state property for handling your animations

example:

```
[{id: 1, animation: 'small'}, { id: 2, animation: 'small'}]
```

see stackblitz below for the complete guide

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfxfx3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html